# Maximum principle for poly-harmonic equations

Tags: differential-equations, maximum-principle

If $u_1\geq 0$ and $u_1\neq 0$, and satisfies
$$-\Delta u_1=|u_1|^{\frac{4}{n-2}} u_1\quad  \text { on }\, \mathbb{R}^n,\quad n\geq 3,$$
it follows from maximum principle that  $u_1>0$. My question is: if  $u_1\geq 0$ and $u_1\neq 0$, and satisfies poly-harmonic equations$$(-\Delta)^m u_1=|u_1|^{\frac{4m}{n-2m}} u_1\quad  \text { on }\,  \mathbb{R}^n,\quad n>2m, \quad m \geq 1, \mathbb{N}_+,$$
can we obtain $u_1>0$ like the case $m=1$？